# Does lastObject in NSMutableArray return a copy of the object?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have a question related to this piece of code

```
NSNumber *lastObject = [self.myStack lastObject];

if(lastObject){
    [self.myStack removeLastObject];
}

return [lastObject doubleValue];
```

I am surprised that the `lastObject` is still in memory despite getting removed.
How is this happening? Is it that `lastObject` returns a copy of the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not a copy, it's just autoreleased. It will be released in the near future.

EDIT: to clarify - on `[self.myStack removeLastObject]`, the object is sent `release` immediately, but you got an autoreleased pointer from `[self.myStack lastObject]` so the array is not the last owner of the object.

Comment: How is it that after being removed, I am still accessing it?
By the way I'm relying on iOS 5's reference counting for my memory management.

Comment: To expand on this: standard getter behaviour for an object in Objective-C is something like `- (Object *)property { return [[property retain] autorelease]; }`, so whatever is returned is guaranteed to be safe to use for the lifetime of the autorelease pool even if the lifetime of the object on which you called the getter is shorter. `NSArray` follows this pattern for array members.

Comment: Ok but isn't release getting called on the last object that is in the array?

Comment: Yes, but not immediately. It's held by the current autorelease pool which will free (release) it in near future. You should definitely read the Memory Managment Guide.

Comment: I would not rely on this behavior, since I don't see it documented anywhere.