# Deleting an object after creating a pointer to it [Objective-C]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does lastObject in NSMutableArray return a copy of the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354215/does-lastobject-in-nsmutablearray-return-a-copy-of-the-object)

I'm following Stanford course on iOS development and I have a doubt.
The thing is that I have an array (operandStack) with "operands" (NSNumbers) and I want a function that pops out the last element and then erase it from the array. This is what the tutorial sais (and it works):

```
- (double)popOperand
{
    NSNumber *operand = [self.operandStack lastObject];
    if(operand) [self.operandStack removeLastObject];
    return [operand doubleValue];
}
```

My question is: if with NSNumber *operand we're just "pointing" to the last object and in the next line we remove this last object, how is it possible that we then return it? I mean, if we remove the last object and operand is just pointing to that object, then operand should be pointing to nothing, so I can't understand how it's possible that we can return operand...
I'd understand the code if operand was a copy of the last object of the array, but this is not the case...

Sorry for my english :S I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks,

Carlos

Comment: and what your guessing about this question? somekind of nil?

Comment: Yes... I just don't understand why that works! If operand is pointing to an object that is removed, operand should be nil or something, so returning operand.doubleValue should give nothing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `removeLastObject` method removes an object from the array, not from memory. Before you remove the object from the array, you assign it to a local variable. When compiling with ARC, local variables that point to objects have an implicit lifetime qualifier of `__strong`.

Since you add the strong reference to the object before removing it from the array, your method temporarily takes ownership of it. Even if the method returned the object itself rather than its value, this would still work correctly, because ARC would insert an `autorelease` call instead of a `release` at the end of the method.

Comment: Think you're wrong on 2 accounts. First, this piece of code would work perfectly without ARC, which means ARC doesn't need to change it in any way. Second, if ARC would add autorelease or release to the operand object, it would overrelease it, since its already an autoreleased object.

Comment: @ValentinRadu If by 'work perfectly without ARC' you mean it would crash on the call to `doubleValue`, then yes, that is indeed what it would do. On your second point, ARC makes the local variable a strong reference, i.e., calls `retain`, and then adds a call to `release` or `autorelease` at the end of the method. How is that overreleasing?

Comment: @ValentinRadu The reason it might not crash as currently written is because the `NSNumber` class caches its instances, but it would certainly crash if the object in the collection wasn't retained by something else.

Comment: You are right of course, as long as the 'lastObject' method doesn't return an autoreleased object, your answer is perfectly valid, including the cache addition.