# Is -[NSArray lastObject] documented to return an autoreleased object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, memory-management

I recently entered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102460/deleting-an-object-after-creating-a-pointer-to-it-objective-c/14102919#comment19513910_14102919) debate regarding whether `lastObject` returns an autoreleased object or not. I always presumed it does, and I never had a problem with it, however, come to think about it, most of the time I used this method, my collection out lived the reference, so, obviously, even if it was just a simple reference, the code would have worked fine. So, it seems I was wrong (based on some SO answers) regarding the autoreleased nature of the return value, however, I tried to find something about it on Apple's documentation, but failed to do so.

Has Apple documented whether `lastObject` autoreleases the object it returns?  If so, where is it documented?  And if this turns out to be true, why did they did it this way? The answer I got in the above debate makes no sense for me, the collection could have retain and autoreleased the object right? This way, the object would have still be valid at the end of the runloop.

Comment: nice question... havent thought about it...now have to think and search :)

Comment: the coca memory conventions.. this has been on here before

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Comment: Wait a second, those naming conventions refer to whether the instance is new/copy or not, not if it's autoreleased or not. You could easily have returned an object from the collection without autorelease it.

Comment: me, because you are asking about an implementation detail and that's not reliably answerable

Comment: well, I'm not asking how did Apple implement it behind the scene, I'm only asking if it's safe to assume, that no matter what happens to the collection, you can use the object in the same context with no problems. That's why I asked if it's autoreleased or not.

Comment: As it happens, Apple implements it like this: `NSUInteger count = self.count; return count > 0 ? [self objectAtIndex:count-1] : nil;`.  (I used [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/) to figure this out.)  So if you find a document that says `lastObject` autoreleases the object, that document is wrong.

Comment: @robmayoff would you mind turning that into an answer, although the docs don't say a word about it (so it seems), your method is rigorous enough to clearly state that it doesn't return an autorelease object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `-[NSArray lastObject]` autoreleases the object, it's reasonable to ask, “Is it documented to autorelease the object, so that I may rely on this behavior?”

But if `-[NSArray lastObject]` does *not* autorelease the object, there is no need to ask whether the behavior is documented.  You *must* retain the returned object, if you want to be sure it lives past a `removeLastObject` or a deallocation of the array.  If you don't retain it, your program will misbehave.  It doesn't matter what the documentation says or doesn't say: the only way to ensure that your program behaves correctly in this case is to retain the object.  And if they happen to change `lastObject` in the future to autorelease the object, your program will *still* behave correctly.

So, knowing nothing else, you should just retain the object.

But we can know something else.  We can disassemble the `-[NSArray lastObject]` method to find out whether it autoreleases.  Then we'll know if we should bother asking what the documentation says.

The `-[NSArray lastObject]` method is implemented in the CoreFoundation framework.  I disassembled the OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) 64-bit version using [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/):

```
75e30 55              push       rbp
75e31 4889E5          mov        rbp, rsp
75e34 53              push       rbx
75e35 50              push       rax
75e36 4889FB          mov        rbx, rdi
75e39 488D3530971800  lea        rsi, qword [ds:objc_msg_count] ; @selector(count)
75e40 4889DF          mov        rdi, rbx
75e43 FF1527971800    call       qword [ds:objc_msg_count]     ; @selector(count)
75e49 4885C0          test       rax, rax
75e4c 7509            jne        0x75e57

75e4e 31C0            xor        eax, eax
75e50 4883C408        add        rsp, 0x8
75e54 5B              pop        rbx
75e55 5D              pop        rbp
75e56 C3              ret        

75e57 48FFC8          dec        rax           ; XREF=0x75e4c
75e5a 488B0D1F971800  mov        rcx, qword [ds:objc_msg_objectAtIndex_] ; @selector(objectAtIndex:)
75e61 488D3518971800  lea        rsi, qword [ds:objc_msg_objectAtIndex_] ; @selector(objectAtIndex:)
75e68 4889DF          mov        rdi, rbx
75e6b 4889C2          mov        rdx, rax
75e6e 4883C408        add        rsp, 0x8
75e72 5B              pop        rbx
75e73 5D              pop        rbp
75e74 FFE1            jmp        rcx
```

If you speak x86 assembler, you can translate that into this simple Objective-C code:

```
- (id)lastObject {
    NSUInteger count = self.count;
    return count == 0 ? nil : [self objectAtIndex:count-1];
}
```

Since [it is documented that `objectAtIndex` does **not** autorelease the object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-1000922-BABBFBGJ), we can see that the actual implementation of `-[NSArray lastObject]` does not autorelease the object.

This means that it doesn't matter what the documentation says: you must retain the object if you want your program to behave correctly.

Note that I'm not saying you should rely on implementation details.  I'm simply using the implementation to decide whether it's worth looking for documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Even though it's not explicitly documented, it's likely that `lastObject` has the same behavior as `objectAtIndex:`. `objectAtIndex:` does *not* `retain` and `autorelease` the object that is returned as per this documentation: [Avoid Causing Deallocation of Objects You’re Using](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-1000922).

> When an object is removed from one of the fundamental collection classes, **it is sent a release (rather than autorelease) message**. If the collection was the only owner of the removed object, the removed object (heisenObject in the example ) is then immediately deallocated.

(emphasis mine)

Consider this example from the same documentation page:

```
heisenObject = [array objectAtIndex:n];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:n];
// heisenObject could now be invalid.
```

In terms of memory management, releasing the entire array would be the same as removing all objects, so you cannot count on the returned object to remain valid until the end of the runloop, even though it might not actually be deallocated under certain circumstances (e.g. literal strings, singletons, other references to the object, etc.).

Comment: This is true, it doesn't retain and then autorelease the object (you can test this by overwriting `retain` and `autorelease` for one of your objects and set breakpoints in there).

Comment: Just a question: Is it correct you wouldn't have this problem with ARC? Assigning to `heisenObject` creates an additional strong reference, so that the object is *not* deallocated even if the array is destroyed?

Comment: -1 // heisenObject could now be invalid. -- I remain firm in seeing it as implementation detail -- they even say COULD and dont make a definite answer.

Comment: even though it might be for a CFArray or CFMutableArray you dont know what it is ... **it IS good advice though**

Comment: @Daji-Djan The docs say "could" because the object could be retained elsewhere, so even though the object is released when it's removed from the collection, or the collection is deallocated, the object might stay alive because of other strong references. It's also *possible* of course that due to some implementation detail, the object ends up being retained/autoreleased by `lastObject`; I'm just saying that you definitely cannot rely on that being the case.

Answer (score 3):

Never rely on an implementation returning a +1 `autoreleased` object unless it is explicitly documented and `NSArray` does not explicitly state that it is autoreleased. The reasoning for this is that it is implementation defined and the behavior could change over time. If you need an objects lifetime to extend past the length of time of the object that returns it or until the next run loop then you should `retain` it.

For example, the `lastObject` method is free to switch between both of the implementations below between each framework version. While switching from the second implementation to the first is never a good idea, its still possible and that would break any code that did not retain the last object before removing the last object, all objects or releasing the array.

```
//implementation 1
- (id)lastObject
{
    if(self.length < 1)
        return nil;

    return [self objectAtIndex:self.length - 1];
}
//implementation 2
- (id)lastObject
{
    if(self.length < 1)
        return nil;

    return [[[self objectAtIndex:self.length - 1] retain] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**if it is autoreleased is an implementation detail and cannot be reliably answered.**

lastObject retuns an object you dont OWN. as per the cocoa memory naming rules: only methods explicity named 'new or copy or allocate' (IIRC those three) return new objects

see: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ask that, I asked where can I find the documentation that states that. Because NSArray's documentation doesn't.

Comment: yes and I answered that :) the naming conventions for memory management. those exist for CF and NS and are 'global'

Comment: +1, but I would state it slightly differently: `lastObject` returns an object that you *don't own*, and therefore you must not call `release` or `autorelease` on it. Whether the object is autoreleased is an implementation detail (it could be a singleton, a "static" NSString, ...).

Comment: Those naming conventions refer to whether the instance is new or not, not if it's autoreleased or not.

Comment: @Daij-Djan: But see also omz's answer, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @ValentinRadu then you are asking about an implementation detail and that is not answerable .. useless too ;) -- it depends on the object that is implementing the array (there are many NSArray classes)

Answer (score -1):

Actually no, why would they autorelease the object?

By calling `lastObject` you just get the last object. It's still saved in the array.
Therefore the array definitely should not release the object, nor should it retain it the object for you.

Autoreleasing is helpful if you create an object, maybe modify it, and then you can pass it to another object, without ever having to worry about it again.

This is not the case, it simply tells what the last object in the array is, retaining is the job of the object receiving it.

Comment: it is likely retain/autorelease to be thread-safe .. but that is an implementation detail. it is NOT passing you ownership though